# Some definitions about RNA-seq

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

I want to select a 10x single cell kit

What does `2x   50     75     100    150     250` mean in paired end sequencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that is read length. Both reads in a pair (2x) can be 50, 75, ... 250 bases long. And I am even more sure you will find this information on the webpage of the provider and if not, you should email them.